# Integration not secure

Tags: magento2.2.4, integration, secure

after installing 2.4.4 intergaration gives an error message "Integration not secure" Where does this message come from? [image]

Comment: How can I solve this problem? my SSL settings are OK. Someone can help me? I have installed Magento CE 2.4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is renderer from
`Magento\Integration\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Name.php::render()` function.

The function will check your **URLS** (Identity link URL,Callback URL) should used with **https**

For security reason Magento strongly recommend using `https://`in integration urls.

Comment: THX, I found it, see this link:       https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: Yes, It would helpful for us.

Answer (score 16):

If you use an empty "Callback URL" or "Identity link URL" for the integration, then run these SQL queries to remove the error

```
UPDATE `integration` set `endpoint` = '' where `endpoint` IS NULL;
UPDATE `integration` set `identity_link_url` = '' where `identity_link_url` IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the table "integration" and you can see null values in the "endpoint" and "identity_link_url" fields.  [image]

Remove null values.

Answer (score 0):

This error message comes from this file.

```
vendor/magento/module-integration/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Name.php
```

Comment: THX, but what causes this message?

Comment: It means your web URL should be secure on https